# FacebookSessionClient Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-8.1

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 Store Apps with .NET Framework 4.5.1, C#, Facebook 6.8.0 SDK and Facebook.Client 0.9.1-alpha.

Probably I'm not doing it well, but I want to add Facebook Login to my app, and to do it, I'm following this tutorial: [Facebook Scrumptious tutorial for Windows 8](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/tutorial/) (I think it is out of date).

This is my code:

```
private async Task DoFacebookLogin()
{
    session = await App.FacebookSessionClient.LoginAsync("user_about_me,read_stream");

    Debug.WriteLine(session.AccessToken);
    Debug.WriteLine(session.FacebookId);
}
```

I'm using `FacebookSessionClient` to do a login, but I get this message:

```
The application configuration does not allow the URL provided .: One or more 
of the URLs you provided are not permitted by the application configuration. 
Must match the URL of the website or the URL of the main page of the application, 
or domain to be a subdomain of one of the application domains.
```

Can I use `FacebookSessionClient` on a Windows 8.1 Store app? I think it is only for web applications.

Meanwhile I'm going to test this [tutorial](http://facebooksdk.net/docs/windows/sso/). Here they use [WebAuthenticationBroker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.authentication.web.webauthenticationbroker.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

so I had the same code sample work just fine until recently. I believe that you have to go into Facebook and enter your ID for your app. once that information is available, then FB will know your app and stop throwing those exceptions. I'm in process of verifying right now.

Comment: I finally make it works using WebAuthenticationBroker.

Comment: yeah so did you notice in that WebAuthenticationBroker tutorial they tell you to set the Windows Store Id?

Comment: Yes, I did it. Now, I can login into my Facebook account.

Comment: so considering that setting the value of your windows store id is what solved the issue, it would be nice to have you mark my comment as the answer. Your old code would have worked with that setting in your configuration. I had the same issue happen to me. That setting is what gives trust to your application and Facebook.